# Why am I getting a segmentation fault when I try to run mergesort on my C++ linked list? (SEGFAULT)

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I am implementing a linked list with a merge sort function for a class project. My program compiles, but when I try to run it I get segmentation fault(core dumped). I debugged my program using GDB, and found that the segfault happens with the pointer frontRef and backRef in my listSplit() function (line 98 in the code below).

Can someone please help me? For the life of me I can't figure out why I am getting a segfault. I would greatly appreciate help with this.

```
#include "orderedList.h"

orderedList::orderedList() {
  listLength = 0;
  traversalCount = 0;
  head = nullptr;
  tail = nullptr;
}
    
void orderedList::add(int n) {
  listLength++;
  struct node* point = new node;
  point->value = n;
  point->next = nullptr;

 
  if (head == nullptr) {
    head = point;
    tail = point;
  }
  else {
    point->next = head;
    head = point;
  }
}

void orderedList::merge(struct node** headRef) {
  struct node *listHead = *headRef;
  struct node *a;
  struct node *b;

  if ((listHead == nullptr) || (listHead->next == nullptr)) {
    return;
  }

  listSplit(listHead, &a, &b);
  merge(&a);
  merge(&b);

  *headRef = sortedMerge(a, b);
}
 
orderedList::node* orderedList::sortedMerge(struct node* a, struct node *b)
{
  struct node* result = nullptr;


  if (a == nullptr) {
    return (b);
  }
  if (b == nullptr) {
    return (a);
  }

  if (a->value <= b->value) {
    result = a;
    result->next = sortedMerge(a->next, b);
  }
  else {
    result = b;
    result->next = sortedMerge(a, b->next);
  }
  return (result);
}

void orderedList::print() {
  struct node* temp = head;
  while (temp != nullptr) {
    std::cout << temp->value << " ";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  delete(temp);
}

int orderedList::search(int key) {
 
  int traversals = 1; 
 
  struct node* current = head;
  struct node* previous = nullptr;

  while (current != nullptr) {
    if (current->value == key) {
      if (previous != nullptr) {
        previous->next = current->next;
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
        return traversals;
      }
    }
    previous = current;
    current = current->next;
    traversals ++;
  }
  return 1;
}

void orderedList::listSplit(struct node* source, struct node** frontRef, struct node** backRef) {    // <--- Line 98
  struct node* current = source;
  int hopCount = ((listLength - 1) / 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < hopCount; i++) {
    current = current->next;
  }

  *frontRef = source;
  *backRef = current->next;
  current->next = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Memory leaks and segmentation faults are typically distinct, unrelated bugs. Which one do you want to focus on for this question?

Comment: Segmentation fault, I apologize

Comment: Which line is 98? What are the values of your variables at that point? How deep is the recursion? (This part of the debugging is easier to manage if your list is kept short while still being long enough to trigger the crash.)

Comment: Line 98 is the beginning of my listSplit function, so I'm assuming the segfault happens somewhere in the function definition of listSplit. However, I'm not sure where exactly is happens. The recursion happens 2^n times, where n is the length of my linked list.

Comment: The recursion happens 2^n times **if the program does not crash**. How many recursive calls are present **at the time of the crash**? Your debugger (gdb) should have an option to view the call stack at the point of the crash.

Comment: Another thing you might try is stepping through the first few recursive calls to `merge`, stepping into `listSplit` each time, to make sure it is behaving as expected and that variables are acquiring the values you expect. (The code example in the question is not yet a [mre], so you're the only one in a position to step through the code.) Loops are common culprits for segmentation faults, so do pay attention to the value of the limit condition (`hopCount`) for the loop in the function where the crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You made *backRef point to current->next and then you let current->next = nullptr. This makes *backRef pointing to a nullptr. Did you later try to do something with the returned *backRef, aka a node* variable in your caller code?

Comment: No, `*backRef` is made to point to what `current->next` *points to*. Once that assignment is done, changes to `current->next` have no effect on `*backRef`. Two-star programming can be hard to follow. ("Two-star" referring to the asterisks in `node** backRef`, as opposed to the one-star approach of `node*& backRef`.)